# Returning file and a message

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc

How can I return and output stream to the user and display a success message to the user? The user would make a request, the back end will do some work and return a byte array that is in memory. There is no file on disk.

Controller would have the following:

```
response.getOutputStream().write(baos.toByteArray());
```

I was thinking about using ajax somehow but couldn't figure out how to do so.

Comment: File uploaded will be about 100mb and files returned will also be 100mb

Comment: The message returned back needs to be custom.

Answer (score 0):

Check out John Culviner's solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970672/14607

http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't seem to send a custom success message back. It only says if it went good or not. I need the user to upload a file which I check. and send a message back with a summary and return the file back.

Comment: Maybe your main page could poll the server until the file has been processed.